# What happens if you connect an AC generator to an AC motor?

Tags: ac, generator, alternator, ac-motor

An AC generator (or alternator) converts mechanical energy into electrical energy. An AC motor does the reverse.

What would happen if we connect the two in such a way that the output rotational kinetic energy of the motor becomes the input of the AC generator and the output electrical energy of the AC generator becomes the input of the AC motor. Of course, some external work needs to be done initially in order to rotate the shaft of the generator.

Is this even possible? If possible, what are the energy losses involved?

According to me, this should function for some time before eventually stopping.

Comment: yes it is possible to connect the two devices ... you are describing a simple mechanical connection and a simple electrical connection

Comment: `this should function for some time` ... doing what? ... what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: According to me, they should power each other for some time. And eventually, this should stop due to energy losses involved.

Comment: probably ... you did not define `some time`

Comment: the rotation would probably last longer if the motor shaft was not connected and the motor was allowed to coast freely after it was spun up

Comment: Is this "beer O'clock" and perpetual motion?

Comment: This comes up from time to time.  I knew a real estate agent who had this set up in the back of his office, convinced that he was going to generate free energy.  He worked on it for years, despite all efforts to explain efficiency and the second law of thermodynamics.  If he could just get the tuning right........  At least the OP recognizes the losses and the non-perpetual nature of the arrangement.

Comment: If you're trying to use the arrangement to *store* energy, you're better off using the same machine as a motor when you want to add energy and as a generator when you want to withdraw it, see "flywheel energy storage".

Comment: Absolutely nothing!  *they should power each other for some time*.  Why?  Are you assuming they be running and then the scenario happens?  Ye olde perpetual motion machine.  It probbly would come to a halt fairly fast.

Comment: This is often done when **testing** electrical machines at full power. Let's say you want to test a 1 MW motor. If you hook it up to a 1 MW generator, and they are both 95% efficient, then you only have to supply (and pay for, and have supply cables for) the 100 kW of losses, rather than supply, and get rid of somewhere as heat, the full 1 MW.

Comment: this is really just a fancy way of hooking three gears together, reasoning that each turns another, and expecting them to spin forever...

Comment: a kid in my HS science class did this as a joke on my teacher using two small DC motors, one acting as a generator. The combo spun and spun and spun and got the teacher excited for about 10 seconds until logic prevailed and he quickly found the hollowed-out motor containing a 9v battery...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...they should power each other...

You seem to be imagining that a "generator" only converts mechanical energy to electrical energy, and a "motor" only does the opposite. The reality is that both machines, in principle, are capable of doing either thing. Instead of saying "motor" and "generator," it would be more accurate to say, "two electrical machines, electrically connected in parallel, and mechanically connected to a common shaft."

When you look at it that way, you'll realize that the whole assembly will behave like *one* electrical machine that isn't mechanically or electrically connected to anything.

So, supposing you have a motor (which also is a generator), and it isn't connected to anything, and you give its shaft a good spin. What would you expect it to do?

> According to me, this should function for some time before eventually stopping.

If "function" means, "continue spinning," then I agree with you.

---

P.S., Let's say, for the sake of argument, that they both are DC machines, and you reverse the connection of the wires.

Q: What happens then?

A: You'll find it difficult to turn the shaft, but if you crank it really hard then; (a) You'll discover that the two machines and the wires connecting them start to get kind of warm, and (b) As soon as you stop cranking, it will come to a stop.

Congratulations! You have just built a somewhat-overly-complicated [*magnetic brake*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current_brake).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing interesting. Loosely speaking, energy flows both ways at the same time (generators **are** motors) and also energy is lost each time it goes around the loop. You could also see it as putting two motors in parallel to make one twice as big.

You will spin the shaft and you will see it slow down and stop - like normal.

Answer (score 0):

You could form a very rough (approximate) simple model:

- Motor converts electricity to kinetic motion with efficiency n1
- Motor loses energy at a rate of P1(w) which is a function of rotational speed when free running
- Generator converts kinetic motion into electricity with efficiency n2
- Generator generates power P2(w) which is a function of the rotational speed

The Energy flow into the motor could be expressed as:

Q = -P1(w) + n1*P2(w) - P2(w)/n2

Since both efficiencies n1 and n2 are less than 1, the net effect of the generator in this model is to slow the motor faster.